# All TOC contents in the same line, without dots and page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am using the `llnc` document class and I would like to create a summary that looks like the one in the picture (it is required by the journal, but they don't have their own LaTeX template, so I just used `llnc`). The numbers in the picture correspond to the sections of the article.

I have no clue on how to start.

Could someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\bibliography{sample}
\begin{document}

\title{Example)\thanks{Funded by Example}}

\author{Author name\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-0000-0000-0000}} 

\institute{Name of Institution
\email{email@example}\\
}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}

\paragraph{Introduction}

Example text

\section{Another section}
Example text

This is an example citation \autocite{name0000}.

\section{Another section}
Example text


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Is result the following MWE (Minimal Working Example} close to what you after?

Comment: @Zarko thank you for editing my post and for your kind reply. However, I don't understand your question. The picture is taken from a published article in the same journal I am sending my article to.  I only have tried to insert \tableofcontents in the template together with the \usepackage{titletoc} that I found in this forum. I have no clue on how to modify it in order to appear as in the picture :(

Comment: If you have to submit the article to a journal, possibly you don't need to care about how things *appear*: just write the text of your article in LaTeX syntax (i.e. marking the structure etc.), then they will use their own template for typesetting the review. On the contrary, if for some other reason you need to visually reproduce that output, you may have a look to `etoc` package. (Disclaimer: etoc is very good, but its documentation is quite large; possibly there are simpler solutions with other packages).

Answer (score 1):

Here a minimal example with etoc package (I switched to article class):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}

\title{Example\thanks{Funded by Example}}
\author{Author name} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begingroup\parindent 0pt \parfillskip 0pt \leftskip 0cm \rightskip 0cm
\etocsetstyle {section}
              {}
              {\leavevmode\leftskip 0cm\relax}
              {\etociffirst{\normalfont}{ – }\etocnumber.~\etocname}
              {\parfillskip 0pt plus 1fil\relax\par}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup

\section*{Introduction}

Example text

\section{A section}
Example text

This is an example citation.

\section{Another section}
Example text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helps.